# Tornar aplicação na Internet disponível apenas para intranet

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação rodando em um servidor externo, acessível a qualquer pessoa que tenha a URL. No entanto, eu preciso que só tenham acesso a ela determinados grupos que estejam na intranet.

Exemplo: "Funcionário A" da "Empresa A" precisa acessar a aplicação. Ele só vai conseguir se o "Funcionário A" estiver conectado na internet da "Empresa A".

Comment: Restrinja o acesso por IP. Se o IP da empresa que precisa acessar for dinâmica, vc terá que usar um serviço DDNS.

Comment: @rodorgas IP pode ser facilmente fraudado. Uma solução mais madura do ponto de vista de segurança deve ser adotada.

Comment: @utluiz Fraudar o IP?? IPs são controlados pelo ISP, como poderia haver fraude? Talvez estejamos falando de coisas diferentes, eu me refiro a configurar no servidor externo uma regra de firewall que só libere acesso a conexões feitas a partir do IP da empresa A (IP externo). Nesse caso, é totalmente absurda a hipótese de fraude.

Comment: @rodorgas IPs são controlados pelos ISPs assim como números de telefone são controlados pelas operadoras. Qualquer um pode clonar um chip ou falsificar o IP de uma requisição, a qual chega ao servidor de destino depois de passar por uma série de roteadores que você não controla e não tem como verificar a origem com segurança. A não ser que você esteja dentro de uma VPN, um número IP não significa nada, caso contrário não precisaríamos de autoridades certificadoras para atestar a origem dos dados.

Comment: @utluiz Estou interessado em qualquer referência que sustente a afirmativa "qualquer um pode falsificar o IP de uma requisição [a nível internet]". Entre isso e clonar um chip há um salto argumentativo, lembrando que o OP provavelmente não usa internet móvel. Considero a restrição por IP medida suficiente nesse caso, ainda mais pq nos planos corporativos o IP está no contrato. A VPN é mais segura por outros motivos, mas me parece overkill nessa situação. De qualquer forma, costumo restringir por IP também as requisições de conexão na VPN.

Comment: @rodorgas Não é overkill, é básico. Falsificar IP é a coisa mais velha da Internet. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack

Comment: @rodorgas Não é só IP. Alguns roteadores costumam vir com filtro de endereço MAC. Da mesma forma que um IP, este é um número que pode ser facilmente forjado alterando com figurações fã placa de rede. Pode acrescentar um mínimo de segurança contra sobrinhos bisbilhoteiros, mas não é nada contra um ataque de verdade. Em qualquer discussão sobre segurança você vai ouvir que o mínimo de segurança necessário para comunicação segura é usar criptografia assimétrica. Uma resposta aceitável poderia envolver o uso de HTTPS mais o filtro por IP,  mas nunca somente o IP.

Comment: @utluiz Através de MITM. Precisa ter controle da rede pra comprometê-la, e isso não ocorre a nível internet.

Comment: @rodorgas A Internet é composta por milhares de roteadores. Roteadores  ao verificam quem está mandando os pacotes. Você pode montar um pacote de rede como se fosse de uma origem aceitável e enviar por qualquer roteador.

Comment: @rodorgas MITM é um dos possíveis ataques que podem ser combinados com IP Spoofing. Mais alguns detalhes aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/q/437146/1683070

Comment: @rodorgas Achei particularmente interessante seu argumento sobre ter um contrato com o ISP. Se alguém burlar o IP do contrato, você acha que eles vão ser responsabilizados?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38211/discussion-between-rodorgas-and-utluiz).